# Format landscape print format via SCSS in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to apply given styles to a page only if the user selects to print in landscape mode (selected at print prompt).  I have tried the following, which does not work:

```
@media print and (orientation: landscape){
  .container {
    color: purple;
  }
}
```

I have also tried the following, which works but isn't consistent:

```
@media print and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    color: purple;
  }
};
```